# DNS resolution got extremly slow after issuing ipconfig commands

Tags: network, dns

I wanted to inspect DHCP messages. To produce them I issued these 2 commands:

```
sudo ipconfig set en0 BOOTP
sudo ipconfig set en0 DHCP
```

After that, I am having severe DNS resolution difficulties. It takes up to a minute and several refreshs to even resolve google. What could be the reason for this behaviour?

Output from ifconfig en0:

```
en0: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether "IPv6 goes here" 
    inet6 "IPv6 goes here"%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet6 "IPv6 goes here" prefixlen 64 autoconf 
    inet6 "another IPv6 goes here" prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary 
    inet 192.168.1.5 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

EDIT: nslookup does not work

Comment: LQ/too broad "...inspected some DHCP messages. To get them flowing..."? Please add the "messages" and what does "flowing" mean? Please add the output of `ifconfig en0`.

Comment: What's so special about google's domain names that you expect those to resolve quicker than others?

Comment: I edited by question. I heard about google circumventing tier 1 ISP by building it's own network, therefore avoiding congestion (and fees from tier 1 ISPs), resulting in faster user experience. Not sure if circumvention also applies for DNS lookups regarding google domains.

Answer (score 1):

Could your DNS server be very slow and you are clearing the local cache of results and then seeing the delay of the actual resolution / forward / lookup after running the `ipconfig`

You can time DNS crudely from the command line before and after the script commands:

```
time host www.google.com >& /dev/null
```